# Rails sort sub objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have teams and staff of which staff are members of a team. Both objects have ordinals which I want to sort by ascending.

How do I do this? I tried:

`@teams = Team.all.order('"teams"."ordinal" asc, "staffs"."ordinal" asc')`

But it didn't work... and gives me the error:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: staffs.ordinal: SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams"  ORDER BY "teams"."ordinal" asc, "staffs"."ordinal" asc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Team.includes(:staffs).order('teams.ordinal', 'staffs.ordinal').all
```

I am not sure how your relationship is setup since you haven't provided that information. I am only giving you a hint of how it should be done